# Using env variables in swagger.yaml in nodejs

Tags: node.js, github, yaml, swagger

Trying to figure out how can i access the env variable inside swagger.yaml configuration file. 
The variable can be access inside the nodejs application using `process.env.VARNAME`. I want to use the same variable inside swagger.yaml file.
something like

```
definations: 
     myvariabledetail: "${process.env.VARNAME}"
```

. I already tried different combinations including `"${process.env.VARNAME}"`,`${process.env.VARNAME}`,`${VARNAME}` etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

YAML as a text file format doesn't know anything about environment variables.  A solution would be to load the YAML and then have code that uses a regex to find the environment variables and replace them with the current values.  Then finally pass that resulting string into your YAML parser.

Comment: I see, this clarifies few things. I will work on that and update here.

Comment: @NikhilManapure, I've posted an answer with library, that may help you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [envsub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envsub):

```
const envsub = require('envsub');
envsub({
    templateFile: `${__dirname}/input.yml`,
    outputFile: '/dev/null', // or filename to save result
})
    .then(({ outputContents }) => console.log(outputContents));
```